# No mex file output when using codegen function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mex

I am following the instructions here:

http://au.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html?searchHighlight=codegen

to generate the MEX function. In the example, it defines the function:

```
function r = coderand() %#codegen
% The directive %#codegen indicates that the function
% is intended for code generation
r = rand();
```

then it uses `codegen coderand` to generate the MEX function `coderand_mex`. However, after completely following this instructions, I can not find a function named `coderand_mex` in the folder,including the codegen folder generated by the function, could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Were there any messages? Try running with "codegen coderand -launchreport" to make sure codegen was successful. Check out the "target build log" in report to see whether build was successful. The full name of generated file is coderand_mex.mexw64 if it is a windows platform.

Comment: @Navan, Yes, I got a file named 'coderand_mex.mexw64', so if I want to modify it, how could i do, as I want to have my own code based on the code generated by MATLAB.

Comment: mexw64 is a binary file for use with MATLAB. If you want to use the generated code with your application it is better to use "-config:lib" option with codegen command. Your generated code will be under codegen directory.